# Laravel the new attributes not exists in the returned API resource when it called inside the controller

Tags: laravel, api, controller, jsonapi-resources

**The resource collection:**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'test' => 55,
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name_en' => $this->name_en,
            'name_ar' => $this->name_ar,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'details' => $this->details,
            'currency' => $this->currency,
            'offer' => $this->offer->first(),
            'brand' => $this->brand,
            'category' => $this->category,
            'specifications' => SpesificationResource::collection($this->specifications),
            'merchant' => $this->merchant,
            'images' => count($this->images) > 0 ? ImageResource::collection($this->images) : asset("/images/default.png"),
            "price" => $this->price,
            "finalPrice" => $this->offer->first() ? $this->price - ($this->price * $this->offer->first()->discount / 100) : $this->price,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'inStock' => $this->inStock(),
            'status' => $this->status,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,

        ];
    }
```

**The controller:**

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        try {
            $product = new ProductResource(Product::findOrFail($id));
           return $product->test;
          //  return JsonResponse::respondSuccess(trans(JsonResponse::MSG_SUCCESS), $product);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return JsonResponse::respondError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

when I use the test value inside the controller it's not returned, although it returned when I call it from Postman.

**What the problem here?**

Comment: `$product->test;` on it's own does not do anything. Did you try something like `echo $product->test;` or `dump($product->test);` or `dd($product->test);` ?

Comment: Yes i tried return $product->test

Answer (score 0):

`$product` is an instance of `ProductResource` And of course there is no `test` property on that class. And it does not implement the magic `__get` method.

So what you can do is either use `$product['test']` cause it implements `ArrayAccess` or first you can do `$product = (new ProductResource(Product::findOrFail($id)))->toArray($request);` Then again you can use `$product['test']` to get the `test` value.

Comment: $product = (new ProductResource(Product::findOrFail($id)))->toArray();
return syntax error :(

Comment: The syntax is correct. But I forgot that you need to pass the request to `toArray`

Comment: But that's the second option. Did you try my first option? That's the easiest way.

Comment: How dear? , i don't understand.

Comment: `$product = new ProductResource(Product::findOrFail($id));
return $product['test'];`

Comment: it's not return any thing.